# Proof for Solution set of the matrix equation Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra

The following theorem is given in David C Lay's Linear Algebra and its applications book

Suppose the equation $A$**x=b** is consistent for some given **b**, and let **p** be a solution.Then the solution set of $A$**x=b** is the set of all vectors of the form $\;$**w=p** + **$v_h$**,$\;$where $v_h$ is any solution of the homogeneous equation A**x=$0$**

I can prove why $\;$**w=p** + $v_h$ is a solution for the matrix equation $A$**x=b**, but how can we prove the solution set only contains all vectors of this form,i mean any solution of $A$**x=b** in fact is of this certain form.

Hope i was able to convey my question clearly, Thanks for the help

Comment: Why do you call it matrix equation if the unknown is a vector, not a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w$ a solution of $Ax=b$. Then, $A(p-w)=Ap-Aw=b-b=0$. So, $w=p+(w-p)$ is the decomposition required.

Comment: Thanks the words " decomposition required" helped me better understand the argument. so any solution can be decomposed into this form **particular solution + w-p (solution to corresponding homogeneous system)**